# Помогите с заменой и печатью C#

Tags: c#, print, ms-word

У меня есть документ: Поставка.docx.
Мне нужно вставить значение из переменных в файл, на место других слов, я это делаю так:

```
static void Print(string[] args)
{
    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
    Object fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/docs/Поставка.docx";
    Object missing = Type.Missing;
    app.Documents.Open(ref fileName);
    Word.Find find = app.Selection.Find;
    find.Text = "Name_Tovar";
    find.Replacement.Text = "два";
    Object wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
    Object replace = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    find.Execute(FindText: Type.Missing,
        MatchCase: false,
        MatchWholeWord: false,
        MatchWildcards: false,
        MatchSoundsLike: missing,
        MatchAllWordForms: false,
        Forward: true,
        Wrap: wrap,
        Format: false,
        ReplaceWith: missing, Replace: replace);
    app.ActiveDocument.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

Как мне теперь вызвать печать, чтобы распечатать документ, который мы изменили, и не сохранять его, для следующего изменением методом печати?

Answer (score 0):

Добавил после строки:

```
 ReplaceWith: missing, Replace: replace);
```

Этот код и печать заработала:

```
app.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint].Show();
```

Но когда он закрывается, он спрашивает про сохранение, как сделать чтобы не спрашивал?

Comment: Пожалуйста, разделяйте ответ и новый вопрос.